# отсутствует оператор “<<”, соответствующий этим операндам

Tags: c++

отсутствует оператор “<<”, соответствующий этим операндам, когда пытаюсь вывести метод для объекта массива.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ship.h:

```
#pragma once

class Ship
{
    char* name;
    char* type;
    int displ;

public:
    Ship(const char* Name, const char* Type, int Displ);
    void Show();
};
```

Ship.cpp:

```
#include "Ship.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring> 
using namespace std;


Ship::Ship(const char* Name, const char* Type, int Displ)
{
    name = new char[strlen(Name) + 1];
    strcpy(name, Name);
    type = new char[strlen(Name) + 1];
    strcpy(type, Type);
    displ = Displ;
    cout << "Вызван конструктор с параметрами" << endl;
}


Ship::~Ship()
{
    delete[] name;
    delete[] type;
    cout << "Вызван деструктор" << endl;


void Ship::Show()
{
    cout << "Ship: " << name << ", " << type << ", " << displ << "." << endl;
}
```

Source.cpp

```
#include "Ship.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    const int len = 2;
    Ship group[len] = { Ship("GG", "g", 200),
                     Ship("gg", "f", 300) };
    cout << group[0].Show() << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У вас

```
void Ship::Show()
```

возвращает `void`. Как вы собираетесь в строке

```
cout << group[0].Show()
```

выводить значение типа `void`?

И вообще, *зачем* вы собираетесь выводить *результат* функции `Show()`, *которого нет*, если ваша `Show()` и заключается в выводе на экран?

Comment: Извините, это моя невнимательность